# Adjust width of progress bars dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spring

I am developing a system which have a list of elements, where each of them have a different progress bar.

I would like to include this ["Admin dashboard statistics"](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/MRB4A), but the problem is that the values of the 'width' are hardcoded for each component.

How could i pass a specific 'width' which is calculated in the logic of my application?

I am using thymeleaf and spring.

Here is the part of my html:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="${proposal.votesInfoRangoEdad.adultgPerNo}"
 aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 30%"
th:text="${proposal.votesInfoRangoEdad.adultgPerNo}"></div>
```

I need to replace 30% by the value of *proposal.votesInfoRangoEdad.adultgPerNo*.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 3):

We found out a solution doing this:

```
th:style="'width:'+ ${proposal.votesInfoGenero.malePerNo}+'%;'"
```